# Kafka FQDN in containers enviornment

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Running `kafka` on a container and trying to create a new `pgsql` container on the same host.

the `pgsql` container keeps exiting and the logs indicates

> ERROR: Failed to connect to Kafka at kafka.domain, check the docker run -e KAFKA_FQDN= value

the `kafka` container is built with the following attributes

```
docker run -d \
 --name=app_kafka \
 -e KAFKA_FQDN=localhost \
 -v /var/app/kafka:/data/kafka \
 -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 \
 app/kafka
```

the `pgsql` container with

```
docker run -d --name app_psql \
  -h app-psql \
  **-e KAFKA_FQDN=kafka.domain \
  --add-host kafka.domain:172.17.0.1 \**
  -e MEM=16 \
  --shm-size=512m \
  -v /var/app/config:/config \
  -v /var/app/postgres/main:/data/main \
  -v /var/app/postgres/ts:/data/ts \
  -p 5432:5432 -p 9005:9005 -p 8080:8080 \
  app/postgres
```

If i'm using docker0 ip address, the logs indicates no route to host, if i'm using the kafka docker ip, i'm getting connection refused.

I guess i'm missing something basic here that needs to be modified to my environment, but I'm lacking in knowledge here.

Will appreciate any assistance here.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to build your own Kafka container? And why would Postgres need to know about Kafka?

Comment: The whole solution is explained [here](https://www.snas.io/docs/)
I'm just trying to implement it as it described in its git [page](https://github.com/OpenBMP/docker)

Comment: Sure, though 1) any existing Kafka image should work for pgsql to connect to 2) editing a hosts file would be the wrong solution. I'm not sure what that FQDN environment variable is actually doing inside the container http://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You need edit container file hosts, you can pass a script in dockerFile like to

```
COPY dot.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","domain.sh"]
```

And domain.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Environment container kafka is: "kafka.domain"
echo PGSQL container  is "pgsql.domain"
echo "127.0.0.1 kafka.domain" >> /etc/hosts
echo "127.0.0.1 pgsql.domain" >> /etc/hosts
```

Feel free change ip or domain to needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it